# dompdf output broken when download pdf

Tags: html, codeigniter, pdf, download, dompdf

In code igniter 3 i am using dompdf to convert HTML into pdf, before I set password with

```
$dompdf->getCanvas()->get_cpdf()->setEncryption("pass", "1234");
```

the pdf work fine, but when I set the password and I open it, the output is little bit bug

[See the pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RE2C.png)

when I download the pdf, the output is broken

[Output when download pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WizYC.png)

can someone help me, I don't understand why the output is broken

here is the code

```
$html = $this->load->view('html_view', $data, TRUE);
//echo $html;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');


$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->getCanvas()->get_cpdf()->setEncryption("pass", "1234");

        // Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream("Name.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));

exit(0);
```

(Update, previous i use ver 0.8.0, i change to ver 0.8.3, when open in browser the pdf generate perfectly, but when i download it the pdf show blank page.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRjDv.png))

Comment: sorry I do not really understand what you mean, Is there another solution ? because I want to use a password to open the PDF

Comment: oh i see, thank you for the answer.

Comment: no, i want to upgrade

Comment: right now im using ver 0.8.0

Comment: i change to ver 0.8.3, when i refresh in web the pdf is show very well, but when I download the pdf just show blank page